# C++, Perform Preprocessor logic on Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor

I would like to do something like this:

```
#define _FLAT_TOP 1
#define _FLAT_BOTTOM 2

template <int TYPE>
void myFunction() {

 #if TYPE == _FLAT_TOP

       int pixelTop = 453;

 #elif TYPE == _FLAT_BOTTOM

       int pixelTop = 990;

 #endif

     // code that uses pixelTop

}
```

And then be able to call the function like so

```
myFunction<_FLAT_TOP>();
```

However, neither of the #if statement blocks are being compiled (they are both grayed out in Visual Studio and the code that uses pixelTop after is red underlined). The reason I don't want to use a regular if statement is because there is actually way more going on in that function than I wrote and using if statements during run time causes noticeable performance drops. I need to know if what I am trying to do here is possible and if so how to do it?

Comment: Please take your code to codereview.stackexchange.com once finished. There's much to improve in those few lines already.

Comment: Names starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved. It's UB to use them.

Comment: lmao read the whole post. I just said the code here is not the whole thing.

Comment: As the comment says, there is already a lot to improve. Are you suggesting that all the code you haven't shown *improves* what you have shown?

Answer (score 2):

In C+17 and later, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
#define _FLAT_TOP 1
#define _FLAT_BOTTOM 2

template <int TYPE>
void myFunction() {
    int pixelTop = 0;
    if constexpr (TYPE == _FLAT_TOP)
       pixelTop = 453;
    else if constexpr (TYPE == _FLAT_BOTTOM)
       pixelTop = 990;

    // do something with pixelTop
}
```

Note that `pixeltop` needs to be declared above the `if` statements to still be in scope when you want to 'do something' with it.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Template specialization?

```
template <int TYPE>
struct pixelTop {
    // no default value
};

template <>
struct pixelTop<_FLAT_TOP> {
    static const int value = 453;
};

template <>
struct pixelTop<_FLAT_BOTTOM> {
    static const int value = 990;
};

template <int TYPE>
void myFunction() {

       int pixelTopValue = pixelTop<TYPE>::value;
       ...    
}
```

Added bonus that if `TYPE` is something other than the two specialized values you'll get a compiler error.